# CSS alternate table row

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply a simple alternating colour on table rows, however the below code is not working.

The body, title and background colour for the page all work fine. As does the hover function. I'm sure that I'm doing something simple wrong but I cannot see the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>This is my Test Table</title>
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #111;
  }

  table.chris {
    width: 500px;
  }

  .chris thead {
    color: #FFFFFF
  }

  .chris tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
  }
  .chris tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #c3e6e5;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 50%;
  }

  .chris tr:hover {
    background-color: #c3e6e5;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Income / Outgoings</h1>
<table class="chris">
  <thead>
    <!-- Define table header row-->
    <th>Test</th>
    <th>Test2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Define table contents-->
    <tr>
      <!-- Define table data row-->
      <td>1</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- Define table data row-->
      <td>2</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- Define table data row-->
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- Define table data row-->
      <td>4</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- Define table data row-->
      <td>5</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- Define table data row-->
      <td>6</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `nth-child(odd)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the:

```
.chris tr.even {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
.chris tr.odd {
    background-color: #c3e6e5;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 50%;
}
```

Into:

```
.chris tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
.chris tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #c3e6e5;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 50%;
}
```

This is because you told CSS to look for the classes `odd` and `even` by doing `tr.odd` and `tr.even` but you never declared them in HTML so CSS skipped them, the solution here will get it how you want it, even when you add more rows.

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hth1LLqe/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

The `.even` and `.odd` you were adding to the `<tr>` element was not selecting anything since none of the `<tr>` elements had either even or odd as a class. You will need to use something like `:nth-of-type(odd)` to select the correct `<tr>` elements.

```css
body {
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #111;
}
table.chris {
  width: 500px;
}
.chris thead {
  color: #FFFFFF
}
.chris tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.chris tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #c3e6e5;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50%;
}
.chris tr:hover {
  background-color: #c3e6e5;
}
```

```html
<h1>Income / Outgoings</h1>
<table class="chris">
  <thead>
    <!-- Define table header row-->
    <th>Test</th>
    <th>Test2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Define table contents-->
    <tr>
      <!-- Define table data row-->
      <td>1</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- Define table data row-->
      <td>2</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- Define table data row-->
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- Define table data row-->
      <td>4</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- Define table data row-->
      <td>5</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- Define table data row-->
      <td>6</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```